# Dojo Datagrid: How to change the style of the first row?

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I am new to DoJo development so this could be basic.
I have created an EnhancedDatagrid and it shows the data fine.
The data comes from an JSON store in a different page.
I have a button which causes that one new entry is created in the datastore and then my datagrid is 'refreshed'. This works fine.
But now i want only as the last step to change the style of the first row in my datagrid.
(I need to make the newly added row more visible.)
But i simply can't figure out how to get a handle on the first row in a datagrid.

...
    grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: strId,
        store: store,
        structure: layout, 
    }, document.createElement('div'));
    dojo.byId(placeHolder).appendChild(grid.domNode);
    grid.startup();
    **var row = grid.getItem(0);  // ---get the first row. How ? And how to apply new style ?**
...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem like this:

```
dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
    var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
    if (row.index == 0) {
        row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
        row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFB93F;';
    }

});
```

I use the 'Claro' theme and it prevented me to set the background color of the row-cells.
The solution was to set the customClasses to a style like this:

```
.highlightRow tr
{ 
background-color: #FF6A00 !important;
}
```

Found part of the solution here: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/row-customStyles-was-overwrite-by-claro-theme-td3763079.html